# How to use Perl command one-liner to extract a string starting with x and ending with y

Tags: regex, perl

I have a txt file which contains:

```
Nmap scan report for 152.3.64.144
Nmap scan report for vcm-7209.blah.edu (152.3.64.145)
Nmap scan report for 152.3.64.146
Nmap scan report for 152.3.64.147
Nmap scan report for 152.3.64.148
Nmap scan report for 152.3.64.149
Nmap scan report for 152.3.64.150
Nmap scan report for 152.3.64.151
Nmap scan report for 152.3.64.152
Nmap scan report for vcm-9322.blah.edu (152.3.64.153)
Nmap scan report for 152.3.64.154
```

I want to use a perl one-liner to print:

```
vcm-7209.blah.edu
vcm-9322.blah.edu
```

I ran this:

```
cat nmap.txt | perl -pe 'vcm-[0-9]+\.blah\.edu'
```

But it could not work.

What is the correct implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enclose the regex pattern in slashes instead:

```
perl -ne '/vcm-[0-9]+\.blah\.edu/&&print"$&\n"' nmap.txt
```

Comment: This did print something, but the output is: Nmap scan report for vcm-7209.blah.edu (152.3.64.145)
Nmap scan report for vcm-9322.blah.edu (152.3.64.153) instead of vcm-7209.blah.edu
vcm-9322.blah.edu. Is there a way to just print the substring?

Comment: Yeah I have figured it out. Thank you so much!